# Network configuration problems in FreeBSD

Tags: wireless-networking, freebsd

I just installed FreeBSD 8.3 (because the 9.0 iso wouldn't run). It went fine, although some packages were missing but I successfully logged in.

I lacked a network connection. So I used my two: `.inf` and `.sys` Windows's drivers' files (`mrv8335`), and called `ndisgen` successflly, then made the .ko and loaded if without a problem. I re-did a `sysinstall` config for DHCP which filled some of the fields but not all of them: IPV4 and submask were missing.

Still, it doesn't work: I can't ping any site, download something from the FTP, and the little LED of my card is not lit.

Here are files or outputs of commands related to network:

**`dmesg`**

```
Copyright (c) 1992-2012 The FreeBSD Project.
Copyright (c) 1979, 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994
    The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
FreeBSD is a registered trademark of The FreeBSD Foundation.
FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE #0: Mon Apr  9 21:23:18 UTC 2012
    root@mason.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC amd64
Timecounter "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 0
CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5000+ (2593.52-MHz K8-class CPU)
  Origin = "AuthenticAMD"  Id = 0x60fb1  Family = f  Model = 6b  Stepping = 1
  Features=0x178bfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CLFLUSH,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,HTT>
  Features2=0x2001<SSE3,CX16>
  AMD Features=0xea500800<SYSCALL,NX,MMX+,FFXSR,RDTSCP,LM,3DNow!+,3DNow!>
  AMD Features2=0x11f<LAHF,CMP,SVM,ExtAPIC,CR8,Prefetch>
real memory  = 1073741824 (1024 MB)
avail memory = 885882880 (844 MB)
ACPI APIC Table: <HPQOEM SLIC-BPC>
FreeBSD/SMP: Multiprocessor System Detected: 2 CPUs
FreeBSD/SMP: 1 package(s) x 2 core(s)
 cpu0 (BSP): APIC ID:  0
 cpu1 (AP): APIC ID:  1
ioapic0: Changing APIC ID to 2
ioapic0 <Version 2.1> irqs 0-23 on motherboard
kbd1 at kbdmux0
acpi0: <HPQOEM SLIC-BPC> on motherboard
acpi0: [ITHREAD]
acpi0: Power Button (fixed)
acpi0: reservation of 0, a0000 (3) failed
acpi0: reservation of 100000, 37df0000 (3) failed
Timecounter "ACPI-fast" frequency 3579545 Hz quality 1000
acpi_timer0: <32-bit timer at 3.579545MHz> port 0x4008-0x400b on acpi0
cpu0: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
cpu1: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
acpi_hpet0: <High Precision Event Timer> iomem 0xfed00000-0xfed003ff on acpi0
device_attach: acpi_hpet0 attach returned 12
acpi_button0: <Power Button> on acpi0
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 1.0 on pci0
pci1: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
vgapci0: <VGA-compatible display> port 0xee00-0xeeff mem 0xd8000000-0xdfffffff,0xfdef0000-0xfdefffff irq 17 at device 5.0 on pci1
atapci0: <ATI IXP600 SATA300 controller> port 0x1f0-0x1f7,0x3f6,0x170-0x177,0x376,0xff00-0xff0f mem 0xfec01000-0xfec013ff at device 18.0 on pci0
atapci0: AHCI v1.10 controller with 4 3Gbps ports, PM supported
ata0: <ATA channel> at channel 0 on atapci0
ata0: port is not ready (timeout 0ms) tfd = 000001d0
ata0: software reset clear timeout
ata0: [ITHREAD]
ata1: <ATA channel> at channel 1 on atapci0
ata1: port is not ready (timeout 0ms) tfd = 00000180
ata1: software reset clear timeout
ata1: [ITHREAD]
ata2: <ATA channel> at channel 2 on atapci0
ata2: [ITHREAD]
ata3: <ATA channel> at channel 3 on atapci0
ata3: [ITHREAD]
ohci0: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> mem 0xfe02f000-0xfe02ffff irq 16 at device 19.0 on pci0
ohci0: [ITHREAD]
usbus0: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> on ohci0
ohci1: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> mem 0xfe02e000-0xfe02efff irq 17 at device 19.1 on pci0
ohci1: [ITHREAD]
usbus1: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> on ohci1
ohci2: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> mem 0xfe02d000-0xfe02dfff irq 18 at device 19.2 on pci0
ohci2: [ITHREAD]
usbus2: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> on ohci2
ohci3: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> mem 0xfe02c000-0xfe02cfff irq 17 at device 19.3 on pci0
ohci3: [ITHREAD]
usbus3: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> on ohci3
ohci4: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> mem 0xfe02b000-0xfe02bfff irq 18 at device 19.4 on pci0
ohci4: [ITHREAD]
usbus4: <OHCI (generic) USB controller> on ohci4
ehci0: <EHCI (generic) USB 2.0 controller> mem 0xfe02a000-0xfe02a0ff irq 19 at device 19.5 on pci0
ehci0: [ITHREAD]
ehci0: AMD SB600/700 quirk applied
usbus5: EHCI version 1.0
usbus5: <EHCI (generic) USB 2.0 controller> on ehci0
pci0: <serial bus, SMBus> at device 20.0 (no driver attached)
atapci1: <ATI IXP600 UDMA133 controller> port 0xfd00-0xfd07,0xfc00-0xfc03,0xfb00-0xfb07,0xfa00-0xfa03,0xf900-0xf90f irq 16 at device 20.1 on pci0
atapci1: [ITHREAD]
ata4: <ATA channel> at channel 0 on atapci1
ata4: [ITHREAD]
pci0: <multimedia, HDA> at device 20.2 (no driver attached)
isab0: <PCI-ISA bridge> at device 20.3 on pci0
isa0: <ISA bus> on isab0
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 20.4 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib2
pci2: <network, ethernet> at device 2.0 (no driver attached)
rl0: <RealTek 8139 10/100BaseTX> port 0xde00-0xdeff mem 0xfddff000-0xfddff0ff irq 21 at device 6.0 on pci2
miibus0: <MII bus> on rl0
rlphy0: <RealTek internal media interface> PHY 0 on miibus0
rlphy0:  10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, auto
rl0: Ethernet address: 00:1d:92:2f:55:d7
rl0: [ITHREAD]
fdc0: <floppy drive controller> port 0x3f0-0x3f5,0x3f7 irq 6 drq 2 on acpi0
fdc0: [FILTER]
fd0: <1440-KB 3.5" drive> on fdc0 drive 0
uart0: <16550 or compatible> port 0x3f8-0x3ff irq 4 flags 0x10 on acpi0
uart0: [FILTER]
ppc0: <Parallel port> port 0x378-0x37f,0x778-0x77b irq 7 drq 3 on acpi0
ppc0: SMC-like chipset (ECP/EPP/PS2/NIBBLE) in COMPATIBLE mode
ppc0: FIFO with 16/16/9 bytes threshold
ppc0: [ITHREAD]
ppbus0: <Parallel port bus> on ppc0
plip0: <PLIP network interface> on ppbus0
plip0: [ITHREAD]
lpt0: <Printer> on ppbus0
lpt0: [ITHREAD]
lpt0: Interrupt-driven port
ppi0: <Parallel I/O> on ppbus0
atkbdc0: <Keyboard controller (i8042)> port 0x60,0x64 irq 1 on acpi0
atkbd0: <AT Keyboard> irq 1 on atkbdc0
kbd0 at atkbd0
atkbd0: [GIANT-LOCKED]
atkbd0: [ITHREAD]
acpi_hpet1: <High Precision Event Timer> iomem 0xfed00000-0xfed003ff irq 0,8 on acpi0
device_attach: acpi_hpet1 attach returned 12
atrtc0: <AT realtime clock> port 0x70-0x73 on acpi0
orm0: <ISA Option ROMs> at iomem 0xc0000-0xcafff,0xcc000-0xcffff,0xd0000-0xd0fff on isa0
sc0: <System console> at flags 0x100 on isa0
sc0: VGA <16 virtual consoles, flags=0x300>
vga0: <Generic ISA VGA> at port 0x3c0-0x3df iomem 0xa0000-0xbffff on isa0
powernow0: <PowerNow! K8> on cpu0
powernow1: <PowerNow! K8> on cpu1
Timecounters tick every 1.000 msec
usbus0: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus1: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus2: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus3: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus4: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus5: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
ad0: 238475MB <Seagate ST3250310AS 3.AHB> at ata0-master UDMA100 SATA 3Gb/s
ugen0.1: <ATI> at usbus0
uhub0: <ATI OHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus0
ugen1.1: <ATI> at usbus1
uhub1: <ATI OHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus1
ugen2.1: <ATI> at usbus2
uhub2: <ATI OHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus2
ugen3.1: <ATI> at usbus3
uhub3: <ATI OHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus3
ugen4.1: <ATI> at usbus4
uhub4: <ATI OHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus4
ugen5.1: <ATI> at usbus5
uhub5: <ATI EHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus5
acd0: DVDR <TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222AB/SB01> at ata1-master UDMA100 SATA 1.5Gb/s
SMP: AP CPU #1 Launched!
uhub0: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub1: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub3: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub2: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub4: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
Root mount waiting for: usbus5
Root mount waiting for: usbus5
Root mount waiting for: usbus5
uhub5: 10 ports with 10 removable, self powered
Root mount waiting for: usbus5
Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/ad0s1a
ugen1.2: <Logitech> at usbus1
ums0: <Logitech USB Optical Mouse, class 0/0, rev 2.00/54.00, addr 2> on usbus1
ums0: 8 buttons and [XYZT] coordinates ID=0
ugen1.3: <Creative> at usbus1
ndis0: <Marvell Libertas 802.11g/b Wireless (8335)> mem 0xfddd0000-0xfdddffff,0xfdde0000-0xfddeffff irq 22 at device 2.0 on pci2
ndis0: [ITHREAD]
ndis0: NDIS API version: 5.1
```

**`ifconfig`**

```
rl0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=3808<VLAN_MTU,WOL_UCAST,WOL_MCAST,WOL_MAGIC>
    ether 00:1d:92:2f:55:d7
    inet 192.168.0.8 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::21d:92ff:fe2f:55d7%rl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    nd6 options=3<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (none)
    status: no carrier
plip0: flags=8810<POINTOPOINT,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=3<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV>
ndis0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 2290
    ether 00:1e:2a:39:64:d1
    media: IEEE 802.11 Wireless Ethernet autoselect (autoselect)
    status: no carrier
```

`rc.conf`

```
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Sat Jul 14 10:43:30 2012
# Created: Sat Jul 14 10:43:30 2012
# Enable network daemons for user convenience.
# Please make all changes to this file, not to /etc/defaults/rc.conf.
# This file now contains just the overrides from /etc/defaults/rc.conf.
keymap="fr.iso.acc"
moused_enable="NO"
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Sat Jul 14 14:44:44 2012
saver="logo"
font8x8="iso-8x8"
font8x14="iso-8x14"
font8x16="iso-8x16"
scrnmap="NO"
interface_ndis0="DHCP"
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Sat Jul 14 15:29:30 2012
ifconfig_rl0="inet 192.168.0.8  netmask 255.255.255.0"
ipv6_enable="YES"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
hostname="NETGEAT_EXT"
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Sat Jul 14 16:02:05 2012
font8x8="NO"
font8x14="NO"
font8x16="NO"
ipv6_enable="YES"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
hostname="NETGEAT_EXT"
# -- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Sat Jul 14 16:09:17 2012
ipv6_enable="YES"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
hostname="NETGEAT_EXT"
```

Comment: So, you took a Windows device driver and used it in BSD UNIX, and you can't figure out why it's not working?

Comment: Yes. I think something is missing in `rc.conf` but I don't know what to put in it. I think it's something like `ifconfig_ndis0="inet someipaddress"`, but where to find this IP address? And will it be enough?

Comment: I think what you're missing is a BSD driver.

Comment: For my network card? Well, there's only a Windows driver which has been converted successfully in both Linux and BSD... So I thing the problem lies in the configuration: gateway and other stuff I don't know where to find!

Comment: What was the downvote for? Did I miss something really big in the process :p?

Comment: @RandolphWest Many modern x86 Unixes provide ways to load Windows NDIS driver binaries. If you're the one who downvoted this question, I hope you'll apologize to L01man, and maybe let him edit his post so you can remove your downvote. http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/config-network-setup.html#CONFIG-NETWORK-NDIS

Comment: You are correct, and I was wrong.

Comment: It's okay. BSD uses `ndis` and Linux uses `ndiswrapper` to load Windows' drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The ip address is not missing, as DHCP is configured. But according to the dmesg output it is a wireless driver, so you need to configure your WLAN SSID + key somewhere, see http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-wireless.html for details

Comment: Sorry for the late comment; I lacked time and had forgotten the root password... I checked the `sysinstall` DHCP configuration screen and the first field, "Host", and the one under it, "IP Address", are both automatically filled with "NETGEAR_EXT" and the IP address. The others are empty. Also, during boot, I see some messages about inet, IP addresses, and "NETGEAR_EXT". I also see "NETGEAR_EXT#" as root. However, `ping` fails and `sysinstall`'s installation of packages using FTP fails too. Is the key in your answer the password for the router? There isn't any on mine. What should I do?